# Sentry configuration in appsettings.json with Serilog in .Net Core 3 Console App

Tags: c#, .net-core, sentry

I'm using the following code to configure `Sentry` with `Serilog` in my .Net Core Console application:

```
return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Sentry(o =>
            {
                o.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                o.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                o.Dsn = new Dsn(configuration.GetValue<string>("Sentry:Dsn"));
                o.Debug = false;
                o.AttachStacktrace = true;
                o.SendDefaultPii = true;
            })
            .CreateLogger();
```

Now I would like to move all this configuration in the `appsettings.json` file because I need to have a different configuration in Develop environment and Production:

Example:

```
"Sentry": {
    "Dsn": "<dsn>",
    "IncludeRequestPayload": true,
    "IncludeActivityData": true,
    "Debug": false,
    "DiagnosticsLevel": "Debug",
    "MinimumBreadcrumbLevel": "Debug",
    "MinimumEventLevel": "Warning"
  },
```

Is it possible to read the whole configuration from there?

***update***

I try the following configuration in my Console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SentrySdk.Init("<dsn>"))
        {
            // my code
        }

...

serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILogger>(s =>
        {
            return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
        });
```

appsettings:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Sentry" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Sentry": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sentry",
        "Args": {
          "Dsn": "<dsn>",
          "MinimumBreadcrumbLevel": "Info",
          "MinimumEventLevel": "Info",
          "AttachStackTrace": true, 
          "Debug": true,
          "DiagnosticsLevel": "Info"
        }
      }
    ]
```

But `SentrySdk.Init("<dsn>")` needs a DSN and it won't read it from appsettings!

Is this the way?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging with Serilog as a backend? I suggested in my answer ASP.NET Core but it uses https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Extensions.Logging/ under the hood. You can just use that instead. The answer and code samples should still show you how to build the config and pass it to Serilog. You can use the Sentry extension for logging to init the SDK. There's no automatic way to pass IConfiguration to Sentry package because that package has no dependencies to Microsoft.Extension*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serilog is unaware of the ASP.NET Core configuration. At least in a way that would bind specific sections of the configuration object to its extensions.

If you're using ASP.NET Core, I assume you're also using `Sentry.AspNetCore`. It's advised you do. In which case you'd need to pass configuration to it too.

[NuGetTrends](https://nugettrends.com/) which is an open source project uses Serilog with ASP.NET Core while using the `appsettings.json` file to configure things.

[Here's the Program.cs setting up Sentry, Serilog and ASP.NET Core.](https://github.com/NuGetTrends/nuget-trends/blob/a24b5f95cfc96215a5ef96e408e02575cd8e4fa6/src/NuGetTrends.Api/Program.cs#L17-L69)

Note that the configuration as you mentioned (with `Sentry` as a key) will be picked up by `Sentry.AspNetCore` but not by `Sentry.Serilog` (which is decoupled from ASP.NET Core).

You can configure the latter, which is a normal Serilog sink like:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Sentry": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
       {
        "Name": "Sentry",
        "Args": {
          "MinimumBreadcrumbLevel": "Debug",
          "MinimumEventLevel": "Warning"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName" ]
  }
```

I suggest leaving the `DSN` and other settings as you did, on the `Sentry` key, which makes the ASP.NET Core initialize the SDK, it will also leverage the Serilog integration.

Comment: Interesting point; but mine is a Console application while `NuGetTrends` has a different configuration as an API project.

Comment: Do you use Host configuration? Do you have appsettings.json at all? You can still use everything I mentioned without ASP.NET Core, just using Microsoft.Extensions.Host: https://github.com/getsentry/symbol-collector/blob/master/src/SymbolCollector.Core/SymbolCollector.Core.csproj#L9 I can update the answer once I understand your setup better

Comment: Is there any sample code that uses Serilog + Sentry + .NET hosted service (and not ASP.NET Core) and still reads Sentry configurations from appsettings.json?

Comment: Possibly on the the samples directory but otherwise worth asking for it in a ticket on that repo: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/tree/main/samples

Answer (score 1):

I've applied the following workaround for now:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.Sentry(options =>
    {
        SentryOptions sentryOptions = new();
        configuration.GetSection(nameof(Sentry)).Bind(sentryOptions);

        options.Dsn = sentryOptions.Dsn;
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found even better approach.

1. Install `Sentry.Serilog` NuGet package to project (.NET console/hosted app)
2. Initialize Serilog logger as:

> Log.Logger = new
> LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();

3. Configure `appsettings.json` > `Serilog` configuration section like:
   [image]

Reference: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/1223#issuecomment-930587997

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541